# How to replace a className on vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can i replace a className (List) into Javascript? I have this code:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
    const url = window.location;
    let urlReq = url.href;
    if(urlReq.includes('/home')){
        document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className.replace('sidenav-main nav-expanded nav-lock nav-collapsible  sidenav-active-rounded  sidenav-dark', 'sidenav-main nav-collapsed nav-collapsible  sidenav-active-rounded  sidenav-dark');
        console.log(document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className);
    }
});
```

this is my html:

```
<aside class="sidenav-main nav-expanded nav-lock nav-collapsible  sidenav-active-rounded  sidenav-dark" id="default-sidenav-menu">
    <div class="brand-sidebar">
    ...
</aside>
```

but i am still getting the default className: `sidenav-main nav-expanded nav-lock nav-collapsible  sidenav-active-rounded  sidenav-dark` when my page was loaded.

What error i made?

Comment: You are not assigning class names back to the element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to replace, simply assign the string classes to the [**`className`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) property:

> The `className` property of the Element interface gets and sets the value of the class attribute of the specified element.

**Syntax:**

```
elementNodeReference.className = cName;
```

**Where:**

`cName` is a string variable representing the class or space-separated classes of the current element.

**Demo:**

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", (e) => {
  // other code
  document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className = 'sidenav-main nav-expanded nav-lock nav-collapsible  sidenav-active-rounded  sidenav-dark', 'sidenav-main nav-collapsed nav-collapsible  sidenav-active-rounded  sidenav-dark';
  console.log(document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className);
  // other code
});
```

```html
<aside class="nav-lock nav-collapsible" id="default-sidenav-menu">
    <div class="brand-sidebar">
    </div>
</aside>
```

Comment: I am getting this error: ```TypeError: Cannot set property 'className' of null
    at HTMLDocument.```

Comment: @AlexanderPaudak, the error indicates that the selector is not selecting any element and returning *null*. It should not show you the error, please see the demo in the answer:)

Answer (score 2):

```
document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className.replace
```

This means that you are replacing the string with another string because "className" is just a string when you get it.

```
document.body.className.constructor.name
=> "String"
```

If you want to replace it, then you should assign the new class name like this.

```
document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className = 
 document.getElementById('default-sidenav-menu').className.replace("something", "something_new");
```